# UNIX domain datagram socket blocks when client address is from array

Tags: c, linux, sockets, posix, nasm

I have a multicore program that uses a UNIX domain datagram socket.  Multiple cores (one thread per core) send records with sendto and one core receives records with recvfrom.

As originally written, the program only polled one socket (core 0).  I updated it to poll all sockets in a loop, but there's a problem.  The updated version blocks (hangs) when I call recvfrom using the very same client address but taken from an array where I store all client addresses when the client sockets are created.

The socket handling programs are written in C and called from NASM.  Here is the original version (it works):

```
mov rdi,[socket_server_fd]
lea rsi,[socket_buffer]
mov rdx,720
mov rcx,[socket_client_addr]
sub rsp,480
call [rel server_receive wrt ..got]
add rsp,480
```

Assembly language on linux sends the parameters to C in rdi, rsi, rcx and rdx in order.  The NASM code above sends the four parameters to the following C program, where claddr [socket_client_addr] is in the rcx register:

```
int64_t server_receive(int64_t sfd, void * buf, int64_t msgLen, const void * claddr)
{
    socklen_t * len = (socklen_t * ) sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);

    int numBytes = recvfrom(sfd, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) claddr, len);

    if (numBytes == -1)
        return 0;

    return numBytes;
}
```

and that works.  Now I update it to take the value of claddr from an array:

```
mov rdi,[socket_server_fd]
lea rsi,[socket_buffer]
mov rdx,720
push rbp
lea rbp,[socket_client_addrs]
mov rcx,[rbp+r9] ;[socket_client_addr]
pop rbp
sub rsp,480
call [rel server_receive wrt ..got]
add rsp,480
```

Now rcx is taken from the array "socket_client_addrs" (which contains the addresses of all socket clients) instead of from a single-element variable.  Stepping through with gdb I can see that the address for core 0 is the same whether I take it from an array or from a single-element variable.  But it blocks when I call it that way even though the addresses are the same.

Thanks for any ideas on this.

UPDATE:  as user207421 mentioned in his comment below, the method described above won't work -- it's necessary to poll in a loop using select() or poll().

Comment: You should be using `select()`, not polling in a loop. Reconsider the whole thing.

Comment: Yes, I've found that out in the short time since I posted this, and I'm working on that now.  I just hadn't had time to update this question until now.